# 'Extensions.GetBotPerUserInConversationData<TypeT>(Message, string)' throws exception

Tags: c#, bots, .net-core, botframework

In Microsoft Bot Framework Tutorial [Get Started](http://docs.botframework.com/connector/getstarted)  the following code

```
        if (message.Type == "Message")
        {
            // fetch our state associated with a user in a conversation. If we don't have state, we get default(T)
            var counter = message.GetBotPerUserInConversationData<int>();

            // create a reply message   
            Message replyMessage = message.CreateReplyMessage($"{++counter} You said:{message.Text}");

            // save our new counter by adding it to the outgoing message
            replyMessage.SetBotPerUserInConversationData(counter);

            // return our reply to the user
            return replyMessage;
        }
```

Has two compiler errors

```
Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required
formal parameter 'property' of   
'Extensions.GetBotPerUserInConversationData<TypeT>(Message, string)'
```

and

```
Error   CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required
formal parameter 'data' of  
'Extensions.SetBotPerUserInConversationData(Message, string, object)'
```

Is there suppose to be another library that extends the "Message" class? I'm not able to find a reference or documentation on MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren't exceptions, those are compiler errors. The sample code seems to be outdated, and the documentation as well - all the methods now require the `property` argument. Just use the same value for both the `GetXXX` and `SetXXX`, and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, those are compiler errors and not exceptions. I was SOin' at 5 in the morning ;)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, and you're right, the sample was wrong.  We'll put up a new sample soon that shows usage, but in the mean time @Luaan has it right.